# What do you call this type of design?

Tags: typography, tutorial

I was trying something like infographic design, typographic design...but I can't find lots of examples or tutorials, and it's weird because I've seen them everywhere!! With those headers and ornaments...
If you know where to find these designs or how they're actually called, if they are called something, that would be great!
Thank you!

[image]

[image]